# Decidability of word problem for group admitting certain action

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting highly transitively (and faithfully) on a set $S$. Suppose that $G$ is finitely presented, and that every stabilizer in $G$ of a finite subset of $S$ is finitely generated. I think I can prove that $G$ embeds in a finitely presented simple group, which in particular implies $G$ has decidable word problem, but I'd like a better understanding of why such a $G$ should have decidable word problem. Is there a pre-existing (and/or more direct) reason that a group admitting such an action should have decidable word problem?

(Edit: Here an action of a group $G$ on a set $S$ is called *highly transitive* if for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the induced action of $G$ on the set of $n$-tuples of distinct elements of $S$ is transitive.)

Comment: I would suggest that you include the definition of acting highly transitively in your post, because it is possible that some readers are not familiar with it.

Comment: I think it means that the action of $G$ on $S$ is $n$-transitive for every $n$, or equivalently that the map $G\to\mathrm{Sym}(S)$ has a dense image. By the way, is there a hope to prove the same assuming that the number of orbits on $S^n$ is finite for every $n$ ("oligomorphic action")?

Comment: Note that simple groups have decidable word problem, but not *uniformly*. This places some constraints on what you might expect a solution to the word problem to look like.

Comment: DerekHolt good point, I just added the definition. YCor: Yes! In fact oligomorphic actions are actually the situation I have, I just thought I'd start with something more well known (and I figured if it works for highly transitive it should work similarly for oligomorphic). HJRW: Ah, good point, that could potentially make it hard to explicitly describe a solution. On the other hand the situation described in my post feels pretty constrained, so I guess it's conceivable that these groups could have uniformly decidable word problem (but I really have no idea).

Comment: If the highly transitive group is not part of the input it doesn't matter if the word problem for simple groups is uniform or not

Comment: You really want transitive on n-tuples if distinct elements rather than $S^n$

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Oops, yes, of course, fixed. (And thanks too for the comment about uniformity.)

Comment: @HJRW What's the statement you have in mind? For instance is it known that no f.g. group with solvable word problem contains all f.p. simple groups?

Comment: One of the most natural oligomorphic actions of a f.p. group with f.g. stabilizers is that of Thompson's $F$ on $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]\cap \mathopen]0,1[$, or that of Thompson's $T$ on $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]/\mathbf{Z}$, they're not highly transitive, so the larger generality is welcome (although these precise groups are known to have a solvable word problem).

Comment: If you have an oracle that can tell you given a finite presentation that it presents a non trivial simple group then you can solve the word problem uniformly.  If you have a fixed nontrivial recursively presented simple group, you can check if  a word is triviai.by enumerating the consequences of the relations and check it is non trivial by adding it to the relations and checking the generators of the group are consequences of the original relations and the new relation. I guess if you don't include the trivial group as simple this is uniform.

Comment: @HJRW Do you have a proof in mind, or a reference, for why the word problem is not uniformly decidable in f.p. simple groups? The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) states (without any proof) that it is, but that seems dubious without anything to back it up.

Comment: @Carl-FrederikNybergBrodda if the trivial group counts as simple you have the problem that you cannot recognize the trivial group and the algorithm for the trivial group is genuinely different (just say all words are trivial). If you exclude the trivial group as too simple to be simple then the algorithm in my comment is uniform but you need a promise the presentation is a non trivial simple group or it gives nonsense.

Comment: I should add by a recursively presented group I meant a finitely generated group with a recursive presentation.  I think Wikipedia allows something more general that is not finitely generated

Comment: @YCor: I don't have a precise statement in mind. My point is that most (though not all) solutions to the word problem that you can write down turn out to be uniform, quite easily. Since this isn't quite true for simple groups, any answer to this quesiton will either  1. also give a non-uniform solution, or 2. improve on the argument via embeddings in simple groups.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: Actually, i don't know a proof that the word problem isn't uniformly solvable in simple groups, but the standard proof isn't uniform. (As Benjamin points out, it is uniform on non-trivial simple groups, but it can't solve the triviality problem.) I wonder if it's known that the triviality problem in finitely presented simple groups is not solvable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. There is such a reason.

I will write a subset of $G$ is RE if the set of those words over the generators for $G$ which represent elements of the subset is recursively enumerable.

As IJL argued, since $G$ is finitely presented the subset $\{1\}$ of $G$ containing only the identity is RE. It remains to show that $G \setminus \{1\}$ is RE.

Fix $s$ and $t$ in $S$ and let $H$ be the stabiliser of $s$. Since $H$ is finitely generated $H$ is RE.

Let $f$ be some element of $G$ which moves $s$ and fixes $t$.

Let $M$ be the set of elements of $G$ which conjugate $f$ into $H$. Note that $M$ is RE and $1 \notin M$ but any element $g$ of $G$ with $(t)g = s$ is in $M$.

Let $N$ be the set of elements of $G$ conjugate to some element of $M$. Note that $N$ is RE.

$G$ acts $2$-transitively on $S$ so $N$ is in the set of elements of $G$ which move at least one point of $S$. Which is to say that $N = G \setminus \{1\}$.

In short: $G \setminus \{1\} = \left\{ g \in G \mid \textrm{there exists } h \in G \textrm{ with } f^{\left(g^h\right)} \in H \right\}$.

Comment: Oh wow, look at that! I'm following all of this except one step - somehow I can't tell why $M$ is RE.

Comment: Ah OK, if $t$ is the only point fixed by $f$, then I believe $M$ is a coset of $H$, hence RE. And if $f$ fixes only finitely many points (including $t$) then $M$ is a union of finitely many cosets of $H$, which I suppose would also be RE. But what if $f$ fixes infinitely many points (including $t$)? Then $M$ is a union of infinitely many cosets of $H$, and I don't get why it must be RE....

Comment: Let $X$ be a finite symmetric generating set for $G$ and let $\phi:X^* \to G$ be the canonical homomorphism. Let $w$ be in $(f)\phi^{-1}$.

Now, $u$ is in $(M)\phi^{-1}$ exactly if $u^{-1}wu$ is in $H$ which we can check because $H$ is RE.

Comment: Ah, of course, much more direct than I realized. Great, thank you! So this embedding result indeed passes a "smell test", very good to know.

Answer (score 4):

Is there an algorithm to distinguish the elements of the set $S$?  If so, here is a word problem algorithm.  This doesn't seem to use any transitivity properties, just faithfulness.

Start with the positive integer $n=1$.  Given a word $w$ in the generators for $G$, run the standard algorithm to decide if the word can be obtained by freely reducing a product of at most $n$ conjugates of relators by words of length at most $n$ in the generators.  At the same time, take an enumerated list $s_1,s_2,\ldots$ consisting of all of the elements of $S$, and decide whether the $w.s_n\neq s_n$.  If neither of these happens, increase $n$ by one and repeat.

Comment: No assumption on computability of the action was made by OP. Indeed if a f.p. group has a computable faithful action on $\mathbf{N}$ then its word problem is clearly solvable.

Comment: @IJL: Ah, this is interesting! YCor is right that in my post I'm not assuming such an algorithm on $S$ exists, but the result should still be true, and I'm still curious whether there's a direct way to see it. But there is actually a special case I'm interested in where $S$ is itself another group with decidable word problem! So I think in that special case, you've explained why it "passes a smell test" that $G$ could embed in a f.p. simple group. (The transitivity and finiteness properties are just to get the simple group to be f.p., so I can believe they don't matter for the word problem.)